# Can a wifi admin see what's on my phone

Tags: wireless-networking, administrator

I have a few apps I would prefer the admin of my house to not see, I was wondering what the wifi admin can see on my phone from the desktop.

Can he see my previous browsing on my internet?

My apps on my phone?

My text messaging? Etc.

I have an iPhone 5s if this differentiates anything which I doubt it does.

Kind regards to anyone who helps!

Comment: Yup! They can see some things, it depends on the exact phone, settings etc. Your question is too broad to answer fully IMO. Where I am, they have the right (we have to sign) to wipe our phones over the network if they chose (or can) since we work with sensitive information.

Comment: @DaveRook do you have any resources that might expand on what can or cannot be seen? I know installing a certificate to use the exchange server can allow remote wiping, but I've never seen anything about actually browsing the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: No, a person can not see what is on your phone, but can see what you are sending and receiving *in the clear*.

There are a few situations.
In general there is one rule: At any point there will always be someone able to see what you are sending or receiving.

In an open wireless network, anyone willing to is able to see what anyone else on the network is sending/receiving.

In a secure wireless network or wired (at this point it's basically the same), wire taps can be easily used or even complete pass-trough can be achieved.

In case of wire taps the same thing as with and open network can be achieved.
Network transmissions can be viewed but not edited.

In case of a complete pass-trough the person or system is completely able to filter, add or alter all transmissions.
Now if there were an exploit to get a virus on your device by way of browser exploits or other apps the person or system will be able to inject it and then eventually get to the point of viewing your device.

Another thing that will lead to the same situation is social engineering or duplicate apps.
Here someone will get you to install something like an app that, while being a fun game also is pulling all your data.

Answer (score 1):

Depend on the network configuration and the firmware, some router can do the tcpdump so the admin can see what are you doing (what file you download, what you browse, what you stream, how much bandwith you take) in real time.

If your apps is using the internet then admin can see the activity but not the apps unless admin knows the pattern of the activity from spesific apps.

If the texting using the internet, yes, it could be monitored.